# Error while using Spring Data JPA mixed with EntityManager in other classes: No bean named 'transactionManager' available

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I was working on a newer project from zero, I just use `JpaRepository` and no extra `@Bean`, 
`@Qualifier(value = "xxx")` or `@Configuration` are used, thanks to Spring Data JPA.

Now I begin to add code to an old project and I saw classes using `EntityManager` and `@Transactional` and typed queries. I think they are not necessary.

So I want to add my new-styled repository while keeping the old code intact, but this class and its test, I see errors:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!

Repository:

```
public interface UserPurchaseRepository extends JpaRepository<UserPurchase, Long> {
    /**
     * Find the last purchase time of a user.
     * @param userId the id of user to search
     * @return the last buy time
     */
    OffsetDateTime findLastBuyDateByUserId(String userId);

}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@SpringBootTest
public class UserPurchaseServiceIntegrationTest {
    private static final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private static final String userId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private static final OffsetDateTime lastBuyDate = OffsetDateTime.now();

    @Autowired
    private UserPurchaseRepository repository;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        UserPurchase purchase = new UserPurchase();
        purchase.setId(id);
        purchase.setUserId(userId);
        purchase.setLastBuyDate(lastBuyDate);
        repository.save(purchase);
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
        repository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindLastBuyTimeByUserId() {
        // given (setUp())

        // when
        OffsetDateTime foundLastBuyTime = repository.findLastBuyDateByUserId(userId);

        // then
        Assert.assertEquals(lastBuyDate, foundLastBuyTime);
    }


}
```

Note that here `@Transactional` is not needed because it is a `find` operation. `save` or `delete` will be implemented by Spring. So, I think transaction management is not needed here.

Do I have to add a configuration class to tell my repository to use a transaction manager? Is there ways to avoid another class? Why can't it just work without while it worked in another project?

PS: I saw `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis")` and `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")` are both listed in `build.gradle`. Is this relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found why: we use a library for OpenID named `mitre`, and this dependency uses EclipseLink as implementation of JPA instead of Hibernate, so we had to exclude hibernate in `spring-data-jpa`. If we want to use JPA-Hibernate, these two will mix up and `@Autowired` will easily confuse which to use, so we had to write typed queries only to use this lib. That is why it is like this for now. It seems that I have to write all the queries myself.